# Redirect Apache Storm logs to STDOUT

Tags: logging, stdout, apache-storm

Is it possible to make Apache Storm write logs to STDOUT? I can see some configuration in the worker and cluster xml files but I am not sure if redirecting to STDOUT is by default or it needs some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it writes to stdout by default, but the worker and cluster xml files are standard log4j2 configuration files. You can use a ConsoleAppender to print to stdout https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html.